# Rate limiting ajax requests in WordPress

Tags: plugin-development, customization, theme-development, ajax

I have using ajax requests in my website to verify data provided by user. Already I'm using wp-nonce with minimized lifetime. But unlimited requested are triggered on that ajax action so help me to limit the ajax requests or fix this issue.

Comment: that should be handled by your hosting provider... handling it in your php *is handling the request*.

Comment: Okay. will check that.

Answer (score 0):

I have setup the google recaptcha in form once form submitted I'll validate the recaptcha in the ajax request in functions.php. So spam requests are neglected.